# UIDocumentPickerViewController delegate is called before the presenter's viewWill/DidAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

The UIViewController presenting the UIDocumentPickerViewController gets triggered its viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear functions before the UIDocumentPickerDelegate is called with any of the outcomes.
How do you present a different landing depending on the choice?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, you want to select a document and then immediately jump to another screen depending on what document the user has chosen.

Assuming this, you could just conform to UIDocumentPickerDelegate (which I assume you do to receive the selected fileurls), check for the type of file, and then just present another ViewController or add a childViewController and show it's view as subview.

Happy coding!

Comment: Because the delegate is called after the presenter view didappear, I can't prevent the presenter to show the old content before showing new one, if you see what I mean.

Comment: I see, so you could just have something like an activity indicator running when the picker comes up and let it run until it disappears. I saw that on a couple of other apps.